# remove double quotes using a macro

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am using this function and it is working as expected. It removes all punctuation.

1. The first problem is that it does not remove double quotes "
2. The second problem is that I need to select text that needs to be processed. I will prefer that current file (all text) corrected by default.

> ```
> Sub removePunc()
> REM the text ranges to work on must be seleczed in advance.
> REM This will be done mostly by a F&R action with an appropriate
> REM search strung and 'Find All'.
> REM the this macro can be run.
> fa = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
> rgs = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection
> n = rgs.Count -1
> For k = 0 To n
> rg = rgs(k)
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(rg.String, "!", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "'", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , ",", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\(", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\)", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\*", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\-", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\;", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\?", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\[", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\]", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\–", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\—", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\‘", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\“", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\”", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\.", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\:", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\'", " ", "g"))
> h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\uFEFF", " ", "g"))
> rg.String = h
> Next k
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: 1. Seems to work as expected.

Comment: Out of 2 quotes the curly double “ is removed but the standard double " quote is not.

Comment: You did not include the standard double quote in your expression, (see the answer from @Yuri )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This works for me:

```
h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h, """", " ", "g"))
```

2. I know next to nothing about VBA and LibreOffice so probably this is not an optimal solution but it works somehow with no selection:

```
Sub removePunc()

    fa = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    rg = ThisComponent.Text

    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(rg.String, "!", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "'", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , ",", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\(", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\)", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\*", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\-", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\;", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\?", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\[", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\]", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\–", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\—", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\‘", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\“", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\”", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , "\.", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h        , """", " ", "g"))
    
    ThisComponent.Text.String = h

End Sub
```

Actually all your changes can be done in one step:

Find for: `"[!',\(\)\*\-;\?\[\]\–\—‘“”\.\""]"`

Replace with:   (space)

Nevertheless if you want to use a list of changes here is the more optimal implementation:

```
Sub Replace
  Dim to_search() As String
  Dim to_replace() As String
  Dim n As Long
  Dim oDocument As Object
  Dim oReplace As Object

  to_search()  = Array("[!',\(\)\*\-;\?\[\]\–\—‘“”\.\""]")
  to_replace() = Array(" ")

  oDocument = ThisComponent
  oReplace = oDocument.createReplaceDescriptor
  oReplace.SearchRegularExpression = True
  For n = lbound(to_search()) To ubound(to_search())
    oReplace.SearchString  = to_search(n)
    oReplace.ReplaceString = to_replace(n)
    oDocument.replaceAll(oReplace)
  Next n
End Sub
```

Based on the official examples: https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/basic/text/modifying_text_automatically/

It does replacement in one step as well, but you can add to the arrays additional elements if you want, this way:

```
to_search()  = Array("no", "never", "no way!")
to_replace() = Array("yes", "always", "why not?")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the user @Yuri khristich this worked as expected:

```
Sub removePunc()
    fa = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    rg = ThisComponent.Text
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(rg.String, "[!',\:\(\)\*\-;\?\[\]\–\—‘“”\.\""]", " ", "g"))
    h = fa.callFunction("REGEX", Array(h, "\uFEFF", " ", "g"))

    ThisComponent.Text.String = h
    ListMisSpelledWords3
End Sub
```

Comment: This command can be used to process the results returned from the above macro awk -F ':' '{print $1}' tt3.txt | tr -d ' ' |  grep -v 'च$'  | grep -v 'ही$' | tr '\n' ' ' > tos4.txt